Spammy Inactive Carts - johnsmith002@storebotmail.joonix.net in Craft Commerce 4
Client is seeing a loads of inactive carts from a spam user
johnsmith002@storebotmail.joonix.net

I have seen these threads also;
https://www.reddit.com/r/Klaviyo/comments/1d67tef/bot_emails/
https://community.klaviyo.com/integrations-and-reviews-39/i-m-having-trouble-with-fake-orders-11872
The hint that it could be Google Merchant Center bots?
Has anyone seen this before or come up against a similar issue or how to stop these occurring?
Only seen this since Commerce 3 -> 4 Upgrade.
